# Liskov substitution principle or encapsulation violation

Tags: oop, encapsulation, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

In this post I wanna to show you a little code example with several JS classes and ask you, whether this code is okay because of [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) or it violates encapsulation principles.

The `_framesMonitor` variable in this example is an instance of some 3-d party library `vqt` that we use inside `Job` class. `_framesMonitor.stopListen()` can throw exceptions, particularly `vqt.Errors.ProcessExitError`.

In this example below, is it okay to expose `vqt.Errors.ProcessExitError` type to the `JobManager` class (**and it's okay because of LSP**) or it **violates
encapsulation** revealing inner implementation details.

```
// Job.js
class Job {
  constructor() {
     this._framesMonitor = new FramesMonitor();
  }

  async stop() {
      await this._framesMonitor.stopListen();
  }
}

// JobsManager.js
class JobsManager {
  async deleteJob() {
    try {
      await job.stop();
    } catch(err) {
      // vqt.Errors.ProcessExitError here
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case `Job` is a concrete class and `JobManager` depends on it directly so it is allowed to know the specifics of `Job` as long as your intent is to have only one kind of `Job`.

However, if you conceptually plan to have many different `Job` implementations (whether the language supports explicit interfaces or not) then ideally `JobManager` should attempt to treat all `Job` generically and should do it's best not to depend on any `Job` details.

Therefore, `JobManager` may catch any error, but shouldn't ideally drive it's workflow based on arbitrary error details. If `JobManager` must know some level of details to issue the appropriate compensating actions then you should try to come up with a normalized `JobFailureError` (or even a return value) that provides the necessary information (it could as well carry the low-level error cause for logging purpose).

Finally, if somehow you need special case handling for every kind of job which cannot be normalized then it will be a question of trade-offs.

To keep error handling out of `Job` concerns you could allow the registration of special job handling strategies with the `JobManager`. Although this approach adheres to the Open-Closed Principle (OCP) it is also an implementation of the Service Locator which some sees as an anti-pattern. When adding new `Job` implementations you would also need to remember to add a corresponding handler.

E.g.

```
jobManager.registerHandler('some-job-type', function (job) {
    //Special handling code job of some-job-type
});
```

If you do not mind some level of coupling between the concept of an error handler and a `Job` then you could do something like `new SomeJob(errorHandler)` or even having `SomeJob` couple to a specific handler.

I'd usually go for the Service Locator approach here, but I'm not sure if we can say it's an absolute best in every similar scenarios.

For instance, if you were using a static typed language perhaps using [double-dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) techniques or even [pattern matching](http://wiki.c2.com/?PatternMatching) if available would be better because you could get compile-time feedback.